# Android Studio Glass App cannot resolve Card symbol?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a template project from minimum & target SDK 15 and compile SDK Google Glass Sneak Peek.

Ive only added this code to the MainActivity Class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Card card = new Card(this);
    card.setText("Hello World");
    card.setFootnote("santiapps.com");

    setContentView(card.toView());
}
```

but the Card words are all highlighted red saying Cannot resolve symbol Card.

I checked a StackOverflow which pointed to dependencies, but I checked my 2 build.gradle files (cause I don't know which it should be) and they have:

Innermost build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Outtermost build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Where dependencies are highlighted yellow saying 'dependencies' cannot be applied to groovy.lang.closure.

Ive clicked the button to resync gradle files but it doesn't get rid of the dependencies yellow warning.

I also get a red warning under the word google:

import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;

The other thing I noticed is that in a sample hello-world I downloaded I was able to see in File->Project Structure->PlatformSettings an entry for Android SDK but in my case I only get this:

[image: Project Structure Settings]

So Im not sure what else to do.  Thanks in advance (Android Studio 0.4.3)

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring the glass sdk dependency anywhere.

You'd either have to copy it from your `$ANDROID_HOME/add-ons/addon-google_gdk-google-15/libs/gdk.jar` to your local project and then add it to your dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/gdk.jar')
}
```

or upload it to a repository and then add it to your dependency section.

Comment: Is that something I do in File > Project Structure ?

Comment: This fixed my issue. Android Studio had been fine for days and then suddenly stopped working - turns out it wasn't resolving any classes from the GDK library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me:

http://b2cloud.com.au/uncategorized/google-glass-gdk-setting-up-the-project

It seems Android Studio doesn't specify that it must build that project with GDK even if you specifically tell it to when creating the New Project.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are now outdated.  Please don't directly include the gdk jar file.

Make sure you update Android Studio to the latest version (at least 0.5.5) and put:

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

in your app's build.gradle file.  (For most projects, this is app/src/build.gradle.)